# snowflake with snowpark error: sql() missing 1 required positional argument: 'query'

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to execute some simple code on Snowpark, but getting an error. I am familiar with the error, just not sure why I should be getting the error:

The code is as follows:

```
# The Snowpark package is required for Python Worksheets. 
# You can add more packages by selecting them using the Packages control and then importing them.

import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col
from snowflake.snowpark.session import Session

df = Session.sql('select * from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf10.lineitem')
```

I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think there should be double quotes round the sql statement, not single quotes

Comment: Hi @NickW, thanks for getting in touch. I'm getting the same error with double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Python Worksheet you need to use `session` that is already provided:

[image]

The first argument is "self", that is the reason it is complaining about missing "query".

`sql()` is NOT a static/class method.

> [snowflake.snowpark.Session.sql](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowpark-python/blob/release-v1.4.0/src/snowflake/snowpark/session.py#L1179-L1217)
>
> ```
> def sql(self, query: str, params: Optional[Sequence[Any]] = None)-> DataFrame
> ```

Trying to create another session inside Python Worksheet will also fail:

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.session import Session

df = Session.builder.create().sql('select* from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf10.lineitem')
```

> snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Connection was already created. We don't allow user to create their own connection inside a stored procedure. **Please use the connection in the provided session from the handler.**

Trying to use `session` outside `main`:

[image]

---

Solution:

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark

def main(session: snowpark.Session):
    df = session.sql('select top 10 * from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf10.lineitem')
    return df
```

[image]