# Trying to execute code in SnowFlake Python Sheet Error: missing 1 required positional argument:

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to execute code in snowflake Python sheet, but I'm getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Worksheet, line 12, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'conn'
```

Can someone take a look at my code and let me know where I'm going wrong.

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col


from snowflake.snowpark.functions import *

# Create a session
session = snowpark.Session()

# Define the function to get entity structure
def getEntityStruct(connectionInst, log, entityStageId, processId, debug=False):
    log.writeToLogs(processId, "Info", "GetEntityStruct", "GetEntityStruct")


    structQuery = f"SELECT * FROM Config.GetEntityStructure WHERE EntityStageID = {entityStageId} ORDER BY EntityColumnOrder"
    if debug:
        print(f"getEntityStruct query {structQuery}")

    entityColumns = connectionInst.readFromDb(processId, structQuery)

    struct_fields = [
        sp.StructField(col.ColumnName, eval(col.ColumnType), col.IsNullable)
        for col in entityColumns.select("ColumnName", "ColumnType", "IsNullable").orderBy("EntityColumnOrder").collect()
    ]
    struct = sp.StructType(struct_fields)

    pKey = sp.lit(None)
    chKey = sp.lit(None)

    pkRows = (
        entityColumns.filter(entityColumns.isPrimaryKey)
        .groupBy("EntityId")
        .agg(sp.concat_ws(",", sp.collect_list(sp.concat(sp.lit("`"), entityColumns.ColumnName, sp.lit("`")))).alias("keyName"))
        .collect()
    )
    if len(pkRows) == 0:
        log.writeToLogs(processId, "Error", "NoPKey", "NoPKey", errorType="NoPKey")
        log.writeToLogs(processId, "Info", "FailGetEntityStruct", "FailGetEntityStruct", errorType="FailGetEntityStruct")
        raise ValueError("NoPKey")

    pKey = pkRows[0].keyName

    chkRows = (
        entityColumns.filter(entityColumns.isChangeTracking)
        .groupBy("EntityId")
        .agg(sp.concat_ws(",", sp.collect_list(sp.concat(sp.lit("`"), entityColumns.ColumnName, sp.lit("`")))).alias("changeCols"))
        .collect()
    )
    if len(chkRows) == 0:
        log.writeToLogs(processId, "Error", "NoChKey", "NoChKey", errorType="NoChKey")
        log.writeToLogs(processId, "Info", "FailGetEntityStruct", "FailGetEntityStruct", errorType="FailGetEntityStruct")
        raise ValueError("NoChKey")

    for row in chkRows:
        chKey = row.changeCols

    regName = entityColumns.select(sp.max("RegistrationName").alias("RegName")).collect()[0].RegName

    log.writeToLogs(processId, "Info", "SuccessGetEntityStruct", "SuccessGetEntityStruct")
    if debug:
        print(f"getEntityStruct struct {struct}")

    return {"struct": struct, "pKey": pKey, "chKey": chKey, "regName": regName}
```

I have tried to establish a connection with the following

```
conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='xxxxxx',
    password='xxxxxxx',
    account='xxxxx',
    role= 'ACCOUNTADMIN',
    warehouse='COMPUTE_WH',
    database='MYDEMODB',
    schema='MYSCHEMA'
)
```

But still getting same error

Comment: It is not possible to create another connection from Python Worksheet. Use the one already provided with handler`def main(session: snowpark.Session):` - Related: [snowflake with snowpark error: sql()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76244157/5070879)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the [snowflake documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/api/snowflake.snowpark.Session.html#snowflake.snowpark.Session):

> class snowflake.snowpark.Session(conn: ServerConnection, options: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None)

The line `session = snowpark.Session()` is missing the positional argument `conn`, which seems to a instance of `ServerConnection`.

Note that the docs suggest creating a instance of `Session` with the line:

```
session = Session.builder.configs({"connection": <your python connector connection>}).create()
```

Comment: Hi @TheTridentGuy, thanks for reaching out. Excuse my lack of knowledge, but can you let me know how I would go about fixing this?

Comment: I should point out that I'm executing this code from with snowflake, so I have access to a a database

Comment: @Patterson I have no experience with snowflake, but the docs suggest creating a `Session` with the line `session = Session.builder.configs({"connection": <your python connector connection>}).create() `

Comment: Hi @TheTridentGuy, I have updated the question to include the connection parameters you suggested but still getting the same error

Comment: @Patterson did you try the `Session.builder.configs...` route, otherwise I'm stumped. Can we see the exact error from trying with the `conn` argument. It should have been something like `session = snowpark.Session(conn)`, after defining the `conn` variable.

Comment: the error is the same as I posted in the question

Comment: @Patterson that's surprising... Try it as a keyword argument: `session = snowpark.Session(conn=conn)` or go the route suggested by the docs.